# Global Data storage in asp.net and SQL Server cache dependency

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, caching

We used to store global data in our asp.net 4 application using Static classes.
Then we came across SQL Server cache dependency.

My question is can we use SQL Server cache to store configuration settings for our application instead of Static Classes.

Thanks,
Daljit Singh

Answer (score 1):

You still have to store the data somewhere. SQL Server cache dependency just raises an event to your system that it needs to reload the cache.